# Sorting Numbers By Last Two Digits Using VBA Macro

Tags: vba, excel, sorting, numbers

I have a spreadsheet with a large list of 5 digit numbers.  I want to organize these numbers by the last 2 digits.  I have a working formula that does this so this is not my problem.  My problem is now that these numbers are organized by the last 2 digits, is there any way to now sort these numbers by all 5 digits?  What I mean is this:  My numbers are now ordered like this:

```
    12300
    15600
    12400
    15700
    12301
    15601
    12401
    15601 
    etc
```

What I now what to do is sort them once again by all 5 digits but also within the subset of having sorted them by the last 2 digits like so:

```
    12300
    12400
    15600
    15700
    12301
    12401
    15601
    15701 
    etc
```

Is this possible?

Here is the code that will sort the numbers by the last two digits:

```
[B:B].Insert Shift:=xlToRight
n = [A65000].End(xlUp).Row
For Each c In Range("A1:A" & n)
c.Offset(0, 1) = Right(c, 2)
Next c
Range("A1:B" & n).Sort Key1:=[B2], Order1:=xlAscending
[B:B].Delete
```

Comment: Create a 3-digit column and a 2-digit column. The advanced sort interface allows you to first sort by one column and then the other.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that.

Comment: Sorry John Coleman, I accidentally deleted your comment.  I have edited my question to include the code.

Comment: Your approach of creating a new column, sorting by it and then deleting seems logical. What you could do is create *two* new columns, one identical to what you already have and a new one using `Left` rather than `Right`. In the sort command use `Key2` and `Option2`. Delete both columns at the end.  By the way -- I deleted my comment when it had become moot. You can't delete someone else's comment (unless you have moderator status).

Comment: Would I add this new column before or after deleting this first column?

Comment: Before -- both columns would need to exist when you invoke `sort`

Comment: I can't seem to get the sort right.  How do I create the column that uses the `Left`?  And how do I sort in the right order?  I know I need to sort by the last 2 digits first and then sort by the `Key2` next but my code keeps getting errors.  How would you write the code?

Comment: you only need to add one column. example: your 5 digit numbers in column A. cell B1 formula `=right("A1",2)` ... copy cell B1 and paste into rest of B column until end of data in column A. now column B contains last two digits of column A data. ... now sort the two columns any way you like ... note: when experimenting with column sorting, add another column and fill with 1,2,3,4,5.....( ascending) to use as an index, so that you can return to the original order of the data (just sort on the added index column)

Comment: Found a simple solution:  Just sort all the numbers ascending and then sort by the last 2 digits using the code I have above and everything works perfectly.  It should anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution in the last comment seems simple enough; this does the same thing (Sheet1, Col A)

```
Public Sub CustomSort()
    Const START_ROW = 2, START_COL = 1
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lr As Long, lFormula As String, rFormula As String
    Dim sortL As Range, sortR As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ws.Columns(START_COL + 1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    ws.Columns(START_COL + 2).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    lFormula = "=LEFT(" & Replace(ws.Cells(START_ROW, START_COL).Address, "$", "") & ",3)"
    rFormula = "=RIGHT(" & Replace(ws.Cells(START_ROW, START_COL).Address, "$", "") & ",2)"

    With ws.UsedRange   'Apply Formulas
        .Columns(START_COL + 1).Offset(1).Formula = lFormula
        .Columns(START_COL + 2).Offset(1).Formula = rFormula
        Set sortL = .Columns(START_COL + 1).Offset(1).Resize(lr - 1)
        Set sortR = .Columns(START_COL + 2).Offset(2).Resize(lr - 1)
    End With

    With ws.Sort        'Apply Sort
        With .SortFields
            .Clear
            .Add Key:=sortR
            .Add Key:=sortL
        End With
        .SetRange ws.UsedRange.Offset(1).Resize(lr - 1)
        .Apply
    End With

    ws.Columns(START_COL + 2).Delete    'Remove helper columns (if needed)
    ws.Columns(START_COL + 1).Delete    'Remove helper columns (if needed)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

Result:

> ```
> Before | After
> --------------
> 12300  | 12300
> 15600  | 12400
> 12400  | 15600
> 15700  | 15700
> 12301  | 12301
> 15601  | 12401
> 12401  | 15601
> 15601  | 15601
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
Sub test()
    Dim vDB, vNew()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim n As Long, i As Long
    Set Ws = ActiveSheet

    With Ws
        vDB = .Range("a1", .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        n = UBound(vDB, 1)
        ReDim vNew(1 To n, 1 To 2)
        For i = 1 To n
            vNew(i, 1) = Left(vDB(i, 1), 3)
            vNew(i, 2) = Right(vDB(i, 1), 2)
        Next i
        .Range("b:c").Insert
        .Range("b1").Resize(n, 2) = vNew
        .Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Sort Key1:=Range("c1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("b1"), Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
        .Range("b:c").Delete
    End With
End Sub
```